# How to lock customer account after a certain date

Tags: magento2.2.2

Is there any extension or solution available to lock a customer account after a certain date on Magento 2.2.2, I.E the customer will not be able to login after this date

I have searched and could only find lock customer after x amount of wrong passwords

Comment: You can use same logic of password for your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Like  Pramod Kharade wrote, You can use this same logic with some changes:
- create cron runnig eg every day at 1am.
- in Cron get all customers and check their last login date - its saved in `customer_log` table as `last_login_at` or use `last_logout_at`
- get current date and compare with last login date
- check that difference is > than x days.
- depends on result You can easly lock customer.

And thats all ;)